# Time dependent weights in hidden Markov models

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model, convergence, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to modify a standard implementation of a continuous HMM with Gaussian Mixtures so that it internally gives more weight to newer observations in a time series.

Essentially, I'm trying to update the M step of the EM algorithm, so that the re-estimation equations are weighed over time.

Taken from a [thesis by Y. Zhang, 2004](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~anoop/students/rzhang/rzhang_msc_thesis.pdf), here's a summary of the re-estimation equations:
[image: http://s17.postimage.org/v6vm4h3il/mstep.png]

As you can see, the only modification from the original algorithm, is adding the time-dependent function $\eta_t$, which in the thesis is defined as the exponential weighted moving average.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. When I make this change, the algorithm fails to converge, since it doesn't improve the log-likelihood in each iteration, and in many occasions it decreases.

Apparently, the order of magnitude of the weighing function matters. The exponential case decreases the likelihood significantly more often than the poly/linear case.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the modified algorithm won't converge? I'm working under the assumption that the proof regarding convergence in the thesis is correct.